# What does the temperature of the early universe tell me?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, temperature, kinetic-theory

I am re-reading Weinberg's book "The First Three Minutes".  In the Introduction he makes this statement: "At about one-hundreth of a second, the earliest time about which we can speak with any confidence, the temperature of the universe was about a hundred thousand million ($10^{11}$) degrees Centigrade".

I probably glossed over this statement without thinking too much the first time but decided to dwell on it for a moment.  What is this telling me?  Could I use Kinetic Theory, such as:
$$
K.E. = \frac{3}{2}k_B T
$$
to compute the kinetic energy and therefore the mean velocity of particles?  Well, I tried that and obviously this is a relativistic effect so I am not even sure if the Kinetic Theory applies.

Is there any depth of meaning to knowing that the early universe was so-and-so degrees Kelvin (or, Centigrade/Celsius) other than it was hot and high energy.

Comment: You would have to go relativistic and consider the reactions between photons, electrons, muons, neutrinos, quarks, gluons, Ws, Zs and eventually Higgs particles. That is what we are doing right now at CERN where the heavy ion experiments have reached effective quark gluon plasma temperatures of $5.5x10^{12}K$ in 2012, which is a little higher than where Weinberg had to leave it almost 40 years ago. What does it tell us? We are getting information about the "chemical" composition of the universe at that time, chemistry meaning elementary particles, of course.

Comment: Did you see this: http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter2.pdf? It looks like a very nicely written 30,000 feet overview on the level that you are interested in.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks for the link to the paper, but I am still a little confused.  Using the K.E. formula I mention in my post, I compute an energy of about 12.9 MeV.  Yet, the paper you provided the link talks about early universe temperatures of over GeV.  Where did I make the mistake?  Or is there one.  I used Weinberg's $10^{11}$ value mentioned in his book which is only one order of magnitude less than your mention of $5.5\times 10^{12}\,K$.

Comment: Hah! You are correct. The order of magnitude is all wrong if we go with 11600K/eV. CERN produces heavy ion collisions of about 5TeV/nucleon, however.. confinement throws a wrench in there: as we heat the quarks in those nucleons in the collisions above 150MeV, the quarks start to multiply and produce a phase transition. That's the temperature the quark gluon folks are interested in and that is what gets reported. It's in the paper in chapter 2.7, I think.

Comment: @CuriousOne -- Thanks, the paper is printed off and I will be reading it tomorrow.